# Getting PCM values of WAV files

Tags: c#, audio, fft, pcm

I have a .wav mono file (16bit,44.1kHz)  and im using this code below. If im not wrong, this would give me an output of values between -1 and 1 which i can apply FFT on ( to be converted to a spectrogram later on). However, my output is no where near -1 and 1.

**This is a portion of my output**

```
7.01214599609375  
17750.2552337646  
8308.42733764648  
0.000274658203125  
1.00001525878906  
0.67291259765625  
1.3458251953125  
16.0000305175781  
24932  
758.380676269531  
0.0001068115234375
```

**This is the code which i got from another post**
**Edit 1:**

```
 public static Double[] prepare(String wavePath, out int SampleRate)
    {
        Double[] data;
        byte[] wave;
        byte[] sR = new byte[4];
        System.IO.FileStream WaveFile = System.IO.File.OpenRead(wavePath);
        wave = new byte[WaveFile.Length];
        data = new Double[(wave.Length - 44) / 4];//shifting the headers out of the PCM data;
        WaveFile.Read(wave, 0, Convert.ToInt32(WaveFile.Length));//read the wave file into the wave variable
        /***********Converting and PCM accounting***************/
       for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i += 2)
        {
             data[i] = BitConverter.ToInt16(wave, i) / 32768.0;
        }


        /**************assigning sample rate**********************/
        for (int i = 24; i < 28; i++)
        {
            sR[i - 24] = wave[i];
        }
        SampleRate = BitConverter.ToInt16(sR, 0);
        return data;
    }
```

Edit 2 : Im getting ouput with 0s every 2nd number

0.009002685546875
0
0.009613037109375
0
0.0101318359375
0
0.01080322265625
0
0.01190185546875
0
0.01312255859375
0
0.014068603515625

Comment: That code is way too simplistic and wrong. Simplistic: It depends on the bitrate of the WAV file how the conversion is to be executed. Wrong: It reads four bytes and normalizes it with UInt16.MaxValue instead of Int32.MaxValue.

Comment: I can provide a detailed answer in a few hours if no one has answered until then. Please remember me via a comment in 7 hours if you still need help and I haven't provided an answer.

Comment: Yup would appreciate a detailed answer from u. im kinda new to audio processing so please bear with me. Im supposed to record a voice and apply FFT on it and transform it to a spectrogram so im able to set the Sample Rate and no. of channels of the wav file via Naudio lib. Thanks

Comment: Your primary problem, as Daniel pointed out, is that you're normalizing a 32-bit value by dividing by 'UInt16.MaxValue'. You need to divide by `Int.MaxValue`, which will give you values in the range -1 .. 1. Also, you could simplify your code with `for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i += 4)`, and remove the multiplications in your indexing.

Comment: Or ... it's hard to say because your code is confused. If you're working with a mono sound (i.e. one channel), then your samples should be 16-bit, so you should be using `BitConverter.ToInt16`, and only incrementing by 2 in the loop.

Comment: Thanks jim . Maybe a more detailed explanation with codes would help more as I'm still quite confused. I understand that I have to retrieve only the data chunk but aren't sure about the process of converting the pcm data to btw 1 and -1

Comment: @DanielHilgarth maybe u can include ur answer as my output is still kinda odd with the 0's in btw

Comment: @user2431088: In that case you actually might not have a 16bit wave file but a 32bit. Try reading four bytes again, using ToInt32 and divide by `(double)Int32.MaxValue`.

Comment: I'm thinking that its because of the for loop I+2 which causes the 0 output for every alternate data

Comment: @DanielHilgarth  i manage to get values between -1 and 1 However i have some values in the beginning which has alot of 0s in between. Is this a problem or is it suppose to act this way?

Comment: "I'm thinking that its because of the for loop I+2 which causes the 0 output for every alternate data": That's not the reason. i+2 is needed, because `BitConverter.ToInt16` reads *two* bytes.

Comment: The easiest thing to to for you is to use existing code. An example would be the [WaveReader class of DSPUtil](https://github.com/hughpyle/inguz-DSPUtil/blob/master/WaveReader.cs). If you have a look at the [NextDouble](https://github.com/hughpyle/inguz-DSPUtil/blob/master/WaveReader.cs#L590) method, you might understand why I said that your code is too simplistic. There is quite a lot going on.

Comment: Hi @DanielHilgarth, I really need help with this Is it possible for u to produce a working code for me to refer to using the above mentioned class? I'm really in need of help as I have been stuck in this area for quite some time arldy.

Comment: It should be really straight forward: `var waveReader = new WaveReader("your filename"); var samples = waveReader.ToArray();` A sample contains one double value per channel in your file.

Answer (score 3):

If your samples are 16 bits (which appears to be the case), then you want to work with `Int16`. Each 2 bytes of the sample data is a signed 16-bit integer in the range -32768 .. 32767, inclusive.

If you want to convert a signed `Int16` to a floating point value from -1 to 1, then you have to divide by `Int16.MaxValue + 1` (which is equal to 32768). So, your code becomes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i += 2)
{
    data[i] = BitConverter.ToInt16(wave, i) / 32768.0;
}
```

We use 32768 here because the values are signed.

So -32768/32768 will give -1.0, and 32767/32768 gives 0.999969482421875.

If you used 65536.0, then your values would only be in the range -0.5 .. 0.5.

Comment: Hi, thanks alot, im able to get my values between -1 and 1 range.If im using 16bit samples, do i need to change SampleRate = BitConverter.ToInt32(sR,0) to SampleRate = BitConverter.ToInt16(sR,0)? Or does it not matter?  Does the code which I provided need more editing as im not sure if this code shows the best result.